# Editing CSS for PrimeNG Components

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I am currently developing a user interface using Angular 4, Angular Materials and PrimeNG components.

The latest component I am battling with is the MultiSelect Component from PrimeNG: 
 https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect

I am simply just trying to make the component's width fit 100% of the parent component.

Is there a specific process I need to follow to edit CSS classes for this component?  The documentation says to use "Style" for inline - does this mean:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCars" [defaultLabel]="defaultLabel" style="width: 100%;"></p-multiSelect>
```

Because this did not work.

It also says to use "styleClass" as a property to add a styling CSS class.  How do you use this?

Lastly, they provide a list of the CSS classes the PrimeNG component uses on the website (e.g. ui-multiselect).  When I attempt to modify 'ui-multiselect' by declaring it within the Angular components CSS, it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For inline PrimeNG styling, use something like this:

```
[style]="{'width': '100%'}"
```

To use `styleClass` simply add:

```
styleClass="example-css-class"
```

This way, for example, you can style multi select input field with many different style classes, eg. Bootstrap's `form-control`.

When you operate with PrimeNG `ui`'s, be sure to put them into components .css. If you use global `styles.css`, you'll have to override the PrimeNG files in `.angular-cli.json`. You can do it by editing `styles` array like this:

```
"../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
"../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
"styles.css"
```

When the `styles.css` are put after the primeng resources, it is loaded after the primeng's, which will override the styles.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  This should be part of the PrimeNG documentation!  Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: note that styleClass can only add styles to the component, not override ui styles. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499851/editing-css-for-primeng-components/45499931#45499931