# Primeng - how to use styleClass?

Tags: primeng

I want to use the `styleClass` property of the `Togglebutton` component. As described in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45499931/3063719), I thought it is straight forward by using:

```
styleClass="test"
```

In my css-file I then set some attributes, like

```
.test { background: red; }
```

But this does not work. Working with `style` is perfectly clear by using `[style]="{'background':'red'}"` No problem with that. But `styleClass` does not work. [Here is the component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/togglebutton). Any idea how to use `styleClass`?

Comment: For most PrimeNG stuffs, you need to override the original styles with styleClass in the root styles.css E.g: styleClass="test" then in styles.css you add your preferred styles using the test class. Now, PrimeNG components have different sections in their styles as well. For example: ui-datatable-header and such. If you want to change the datatable's header's style, you need to do .test .ui-datatable-header { } You might want to utilize Chrome Dev Tools to find the exact elements you want to style. (I am my phone so it's hard to make a plunker)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ChauTran. I found out that the only way to use this property is to set `Viewencapsulation` to `none`. In addition, I had to use the original classes of the component, which looks like this: `.test.ui-state-highlight, .test.ui-togglebutton.ui-button.ui-state-active {}`. I couldn't find any other way to work with `styleClass`

Comment: I am glad you found a solution. And yes, that's pretty much the only way to work with `styleClass`. And `styleClass` is to just differentiate between different similar components (like two dataTables).

Comment: @Chau Tran 
"And styleClass is to just differentiate between different similar components".

That is the point I was not aware of. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Dont forget to import styles in angular.js file

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To make things clear: the `styleClass` property is only an addition to the original classes of the component. That means, you always have to use the original classes in order to style the component. With `styleClass` you then have the possibility to address one or more components of a set of components of the same type. So, having five `Togglebutton` components, you can generally style those components with

```
.ui-togglebutton.ui-button.ui-state-active{}
```

If you then want to style one of those components differently, you can add the `styleClass` property:

```
<p-toggleButton styleClass="different"></p-toggleButton>
```

And in your css you can now address this one by:

```
.different.ui-togglebutton.ui-button.ui-state-active{}
```

Thus `styleClass` is not a replacement for the original selectors, it is an addition.

Comment: Do we have to set encapsulation to none to use these css?
Because directly it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to override o PrimeNg component doing this, eg. I was using tabMenu and worked:

```
<p-tabMenu styleClass="override-this"></p-tabMenu>
```

I suppose it will work with any PrimeNg component that accepts styleClass.

In ***root style.css*** file you just use body and then the styleClass name.

```
body .override-this{
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

I didn't test with other properties, probably if you need to change some deeper you will need to cascade like

`body .override-this .ui-tabmenu .ui-tabmenu-nav` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the view encapsulation on, another option is to use `:host` together with `::ng-deep`

```
:host ::ng-deep .test {
    background: red;
}
```

Note that `::ng-deep` might be removed in the future. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep) SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Example for p-dropdown

```
.p-dropdown {
  &.add-attr-dropdown {
    border: 0px;
  }
}
```

Here `add-attr-dropdown` is your custom class name